# why do I get this error - Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have the following error...

> Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

I have no idea why because as far as I can tell I have provided a unique key for my map.

All reference material I can find on this warning relates to the use of rendered lists which I do not have. I merely am mapping the data to my slides on a separate component.

My code runs absolutely fine and is shown on the page as intended, I just have this annoying error and don't know how to resolve it.

Here is my code...

```
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from "swiper/react";
import { Virtual, Navigation, FreeMode } from "swiper";
import { SongCard } from "./Songcard";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useQuery } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import Link from "next/link";
import fetchSongs from "../utils/getSongs";

import "swiper/css";
import "swiper/css/virtual";
import "swiper/css/navigation";
import "swiper/css/free-mode";

export default function Slider() {
  const [songData, setSongData] = useState([]);

  const { data, status } = useQuery(["songs"], fetchSongs, {
    staleTime: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24,
    cacheTime: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (status === "success") {
      setSongData(data);
    }
  }, [status]);

  return (
    <Swiper
      key={songData}
      //onSwiper={(swiper) => console.log(swiper)}
      modules={[Virtual, Navigation, FreeMode]}
      slidesPerView={6}
      slidesOffsetBefore={-106}
      virtual
      navigation={true}
      grabCursor={true}
      breakpoints={{
        280: {
          slidesPerView: 1,
        },
        350: {
          slidesPerView: 2,
          spaceBetween: 50,
        },
        500: {
          slidesPerView: 2,
        },
        638: {
          slidesPerView: 3,
        },
        820: {
          slidesPerView: 4,
        },
        1060: {
          slidesPerView: 5,
        },

        1260: {
          slidesPerView: 6,
        },
      }}
    >
      {songData.map((song) => (
        <SwiperSlide key={song.songId}>
          <Link href={`/artist/${song.userId}`} passHref>
            <SongCard data={song} />
          </Link>
        </SwiperSlide>
      ))}
    </Swiper>
  );
}
```

Where would I add a further unique Key to my map? Doesn't make sense to me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like songId is not unique

Comment: Are you sure the error is about this part of the code? If song ids weren't unique you would see a different error stating there are multiple items with the same key

Comment: songId's are derived from doc.id which are unique document references.

Comment: On second look songId (doc.id) is not actually being generated in the fetchData so I think that is the problem. I need to songId: doc.id in to my fetch. thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the final code i ended up using to generate my songId value...

```
export default async function fetchSongs() {
  const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "songs"));
  const songs = [];
  querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    songs.push({ ...doc.data(), songId: doc.id });
  });
  return songs;
}
```

Thanks for the hints and tips people!